# What is the point of knacks like animal-lore or dodge at level 1?

Tags: skills, balance, warriors-adventure

In the Warrior Adventure Game, animal lore (at level 1) gives +1 per intelligence chip on intelligence or ponder for animal-related checks.

First, ponder is an intelligence skill, so why is it mentioned separately? Second, what's the point when I can get a +1 per chip anyway?

Likewise, dodge gives +1 per spirit chip on jump for dodge checks. Again, I can do the same without that knack.

Is there any value in having such knacks at level 1, or is it just a starting point for getting higher bonuses at later levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## They can change the difficulty of a check

You are correct that the Knacks you listed seem to give you abilities that you already have. You can already spend an Intelligence chip to boost skill for a Ponder check, or a Spirit chip for a Jump check. At level one, this does not give you anything better than that necessarily, other than the opportunity to grow better.

There is one difference mentioned in the "Using Knacks" section in Chapter 5 of the rules (page 28):

> Also, the details of an
> adventure may list special effects, bonuses, or
> (sometimes) even penalties for using certain Knacks at
> certain times.

Using one of these Knacks may enable you to have an easier (or harder) time on a specific check as determined by the Narrator. An example of this is given in the sample adventure "Saving the Kits" included with the rules (page 47):

> **Read Aloud:** “Thanks to yesterday’s rain, the ground
> here is still fairly muddy. After only a few minutes of
> poking around, you are able to identify two distinct sets
> of paw prints.”
> ...
> *Animal Lore or Ponder:* Knowledge about other
> animals will help tell the difference between the tracks.
> An Animal Lore Check that totals 4 or higher or a Ponder
> Check that totals 5 or higher will let the cat know that the
> tracks that lead into the meadow were made by a skunk.